# Problem inserting C# POCO class in LiteDB

Tags: c#, litedb

I have the following code to insert my POCO into a LiteDB instance.

Here is the POCO:

```
public class FileTranslationData
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string FileLocation { get; set; }
    public string FileJSONLocation { get; set; }
    public int TranslationRetries { get; set; }
    public string TranslationStatus { get; set; }
    public string TranslationId { get; set; }
    public string FileTranslationURL { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the call to insert the data into the collection:

```
public string SaveFileTranslationStatus([FromServices] LiteDbContext db, FileTranslationData data, string Collection)
{
    var files = db.Context.GetCollection(Collection);
    files.Insert(data);
    files.EnsureIndex(x => x.id);
    return null;            
}
```

The `files.Insert(data)` line is throwing an error:

> Arguement 1: cannot convert from 'LargeFileDownload.Models.FileTranslationData' to 'LiteDB.BsonDocument'

I have read the documentation for LiteDB and it says it can handle inserting POCO objects. I have an ID field that I want to sent the index on as well. What am I missing here?

Comment: Why `return null;`? Why not just make the method void?

Comment: I'm stubbing in this code right now, so I am returning null until I get the rest of the code in place to return the correct value.  I have updated the code to return the Id after the insert into the file.

Answer (score 3):

Well that was a quick fix, and this is entirely my fault, but I am posting my answer here for others who may have made the same mistake I did.  This line

```
var files = db.Context.GetCollection(Collecton);
```

Needed to be changed to:

```
var files = db.Context.GetCollection<FileTranslationData>(Collecton);
```

Without passing the collection type, it assumes a generic Bson document.  Once I put in the document type, it all worked.